# React-query-devtools issue

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I installed the react query devtools and I got an error when trying to start the app, the code and the error snapshots are above, any help, thank you.
`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query-devtools';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      {' '}
      <App />
      <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'queries' of undefined

 export const ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel = React.forwardRef(
> 215 |   function ReactQueryDevtoolsPanel(props, ref) {
  216 |     const { setIsOpen, ...panelProps } = props
  217 | 
  218 |     const queryCache = useQueryCache ? useQueryCache() : cache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the code, you are using react-query v3. The separate react-query-devtools package is for v2 only. With v3, please use the devtools that come with react-query:

`import { ReactQueryDevtools } from 'react-query/devtools';`

Answer (score 0):

Write these import statement

```
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from "react-query/devtools";
```

write these before QueryClientProvider

```
<ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} position="bottom-right" />
```

Comment: keeping initialIsOpen false or true is your choice and position also depends on requirement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think this is has a simple solution! you forgot to assign a value to initialIsOpen, if it doesnt have one yet try assigning it an empty string